# Binsize for Compound Poisson Gamma Distribution?

Tags: gamma-distribution, poisson-process

Having data of a (putative) Poisson-Gamma process I am looking for a method to define the correct binsize for analysing my data. I need a certain range (!) of binsizes (for instance starting with binsize 1, 2 ...10) to do variance versus median plots because I want to measure P of the relationship
$$
   var(X)\sim E(X)^P
$$
For a range of larger binsizes the gamma-character seems to be overestimated and the Poisson-character underestimated. Actually, I would appreciate a method to define the binsize ranges in dependence of the data only. To give an example, the following heuristic approach delivers good results for (pure) gamma data that I tested (but not for poisson):

```r
cut.tester <- function (x)

    {
        huz <- deparse (substitute (x))
        x.mean <- mean (x)           
        x.rel <- mean(x)/10 minimal binsize and
        max.rel <- x.mean 
        binsize <- seq (x.rel, max.rel, by=x.rel)     
        mat <- t(sapply (binsize, function (bz)
                         {                            
        hh <- tabulate (cut (x, seq(0, max (x), by=bz)))
        mat.mean <- mean (hh)
        mat.var <- var (hh)
        kleist <- c(mat.var, mat.mean)
    }
                         )
                 )
        mydata <- as.data.frame (mat)
        colnames (mydata) <- c("var", "mean")
         x.rel <- format (x.rel, digits = 2)
        max.rel <- format (max.rel, digits = 2)        
        data.fit <- lm (log(var)~log(mean), data=mydata)
        alpha <- format (data.fit$coefficients[2], digits=4)
    r.quad <- format (summary (data.fit)$r.squared, digits=4)
        plot (log(var)~log(mean), data=mydata, 
           main="Variance versus Mean", 
           xlab="log mean", ylab="log variance")
        legend ("topleft",c(paste ("alpha", alpha, sep=" = "), 
         paste("r2", r.quad, sep=" = "), 
         paste ("min.bin", x.rel, sep=" = "), 
         paste ("max.bin", max.rel, sep=" = "), 
         paste ("steps", x.rel, sep=" = ")), bty="n")
        mtext (huz, side=3, cex=0.6)
        abline (data.fit, col="red")
    }
```

What is the best way to define a range of binsizes to analyse a compound-poisson-gamma-process?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not completely clear to me. But I guess you are interested in measuring P of the variance to mean power function that is typical for the tweedie family of distributions.

$$
var(x) \sim [E(x)]^P
$$
For normal P=0, Poisson P=1, compound Poisson gamma 1 < P < 2, gamma P=2, inverse Gaussian P=3.

Principally, doing a variance versus mean plot for measuring P is not a bad idea. But is is not the only method to measure P and it is not that precise.  tweedie.profile of the R-package "tweedie" offers different approaches, all based on a maximum likelihood estimation of the tweedie index parameter P.

Hope this helps
Wim

Comment: Welcome to the site. This seems a bit more like a comment than an answer at present. Would you mind expanding a little on tweedie & explaining how it will help the OP / resolve the issue?